# Estimating the expected supremum of the absolute value of a Gaussian process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, normal-distribution

I'm currently reading a famous paper of Talagrand and fail to "easily see" that for a Gaussian process $(X_t)_{t\in T}$ and any $t_0 \in T$ one has

$$ E \sup_T | X_t | \leq E |X_{t_0}| + 2E \sup_T \, X_t $$

Could anybody please provide some details?

For reference: The statement appears in (1) on page 2 of [Regularity of gaussian processes](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/acta-mathematica/volume-159/issue-none/Regularity-of-gaussian-processes/10.1007/BF02392556.full)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, as a small point of clarification: this holds for *centered* Gaussian processes, so $\mathbb{E}[X_t] = 0$ is constant.

Now, define $Y_t := X_t - X_{t_0}$.  We have $$\mathbb{E}\left[\sup_{t \in T} |X_t|\right] \le \mathbb{E}[|X_{t_0}|] + \mathbb{E}\left[\sup_{t \in T} |Y_t|\right].$$  We write $Y = Y^+ - Y^-$, where $Y^+_t = Y_t 1_{Y_t \ge 0}$ and $Y^- = -Y_t 1_{Y_t \le 0}$.  Because $Y$ is symmetric, $Y^+$ and $Y^-$ have the same law, so
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\left[\sup_{t \in T} |Y_t|\right] &\le \mathbb{E}\left[\sup_{t \in T} Y^+_t\right] + \mathbb{E}\left[\sup_{t \in T} Y^-_t\right] \\
&= 2 \mathbb{E}\left[\sup_{t \in T} Y^+_t\right] \\
&= 2 \mathbb{E}\left[\sup_{t \in T} Y_t\right],
\end{align*}
where the last equality follows from the fact that $Y_{t_0} = 0$ so $\sup_{t \in T} Y_t = \sup_{t \in T} Y_t 1_{Y_t \ge 0}$.  Finally, we have
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\left[\sup_{t \in T} Y_t\right] &= \mathbb{E}\left[\sup_{t \in T} (X_t - X_{t_0})\right] \\
&= \mathbb{E}\left[\sup_{t \in T} X_t\right] - \mathbb{E}[X_{t_0}] \\
&= \mathbb{E}\left[\sup_{t \in T} X_t\right].
\end{align*}
Combining everything, we thus conclude the desired inequality
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\left[\sup_{t \in T} |X_t|\right] &\le \mathbb{E}[|X_{t_0}|] + \mathbb{E}\left[\sup_{t \in T} |Y_t|\right] \\
&\le \mathbb{E}[|X_{t_0}|] + 2 \mathbb{E}\left[\sup_{t \in T} Y_t \right] \\
&= \mathbb{E}[|X_{t_0}|] + 2 \mathbb{E}\left[\sup_{t \in T} X_t \right] 
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you very much!